# Unable to specify a non-root nginx location to angular container

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to containerize my website which originally has an angular project that takes care of certain actions, the front page is a static bootstrapped webpage, and an Nginx reverse proxy that routes the request to the required application. 
I'm trying to move the three components to three different docker containers. However, the angular container is not getting routed to for a very specific use case which is the one that I need.

My code is given below, additionally, I'm using a blank angular project to test it out which I created with `ng new test-project`.

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.4"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "./config/:/etc/nginx/"

  bootstrap:
    image: bootstrap_image
    ports:
      - "8889:80" # Just for testing

  angular:
    image: angular_image
    ports:
      - "8888:80" # Just for testing
```

Dockerfile for Angular App

```
##############
# build dist #
##############
FROM node as build

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
RUN ["npm", "install"]
RUN ["npm", "install", "-g", "@angular/cli"]

COPY . .

RUN ["ng", "build"]


##############
# prod image #
##############
FROM nginx:alpine as prod

COPY --from=build /app/dist/test-project /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

The bootstrap image also uses the same nginx:alpine image and just copies the html files to `/usr/share/nginx/html`

Nginx Reverse Proxy Configuration

```
server {
        listen 80;
        # root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # index index.html index.htm;

        location /home {
            proxy_pass http://angular:80/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://bootstrap:80/;
        }

}
```

The configuration is very straightforward currently. On debugging, I found out the following facts:

1. When I swap the location checker for the two containers (/ on angular, /home on bootstrap), it works.
2. When I go to `localhost:80/home`, it never hits the angular container.
3. When I swap the angular service with another container based on the bootstrap image, `localhost:80/home` hits the service appropriately.
4. Although the angular page doesn't load, the title on the tab shows up correctly.

I've no idea what could be causing this because the two containers are definitely working. I tested this by accessing `localhost:8888` and `localhost:8889`. My conclusion currently is that something is wrong with the way angular builds the application and maybe I need to do something to the `angular.json` file to fix this.
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into whether or not the Angular container is using http redirects or trying to load additional resources by relative address. i.e. if angular thinks it's root address is http://angular:80/ and it tries to tell clients to load http://angular:80/index.html (for example), clients won't be able to find that. Nginx `proxy_pass` is one-way only, there are other directives you would need to add: `proxy_redirect` and (I think) `proxy_set_header HOST`